# Array of arrays (Python/NumPy)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am using Python/NumPy, and I have two arrays like the following:

```
array1 = [1 2 3]
array2 = [4 5 6]
```

And I would like to create a new array:

```
array3 = [[1 2 3], [4 5 6]]
```

and append items to it. So for example if the new items to append are:

```
array4 = [7 8 9]
array5 = [10 11 12]
```

Then now array3 would be an array with two rows and two columns like the one shown below:

```
array3= [[1 2 3], [4 5 6]
         [7 8 9], [10 11 12]]
```

I seem to have problems because the elements of my arrays are not separated by commas.

Comment: Why not just separate the elements of your arrays by commas?

Comment: If that's the only option, I guess I will have to do that. I am importing a tab delimited text file to analyze in python, and python keeps the elements separated by a tab. I was hoping the conversion from tab to comma separation would be redundant, but I may be wrong (it seems to be an issue here).

Comment: What does "python keeps the elements separated by a tab" mean? Are the rows still strings?  What does `print repr(array1)` give?

Comment: Actually, print repr(array1) gives me array([1,2,3]). Now I am confused...

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the simplest way to extend a numpy array in 2 dimensions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/877479/whats-the-simplest-way-to-extend-a-numpy-array-in-2-dimensions)

Comment: Solved: maybe not the most elegant way to do this, but decided to work on the repr(array), in order to avoid all the problems related to tabs. Somehow it worked for me. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 15):

It seems strange that you would write arrays without commas (is that a [MATLAB syntax](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html)?)

Have you tried going through [NumPy's documentation on multi-dimensional arrays](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.ndarray.html)?

It seems NumPy has a ["Python-like" append method to add items to a NumPy n-dimensional array](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.append.html?highlight=append#numpy.append):

```
>>> p = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])

>>> p = np.append(p, [[5,6]], 0)

>>> p = np.append(p, [[7],[8],[9]],1)

>>> p
array([[1, 2, 7], [3, 4, 8], [5, 6, 9]])
```

It has also [been answered already](https://stackoverflow.com/a/877564/484127)...

From the [documentation for MATLAB users](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html):

You could use a matrix constructor which takes a string in the form of a matrix MATLAB literal:

```
mat("1 2 3; 4 5 6")
```

or

```
matrix("[1 2 3; 4 5 6]")
```

Please give it a try and tell me how it goes.

Comment: The data is imported from a tab delimited text file. Appending items separated with commas is trivial. Still unclear how to append tab delimited data. Trying to find out how to convert the tab delimited stuff into comma-separated data. Not aware that the tab-delimited part has been answered already. Thanks.

Comment: Tried editing my answer by guessing the input. If i'm wrong, please update your question with the exact form of imput (i.e: 1 2 3\t 4 5 6 .. etc)

Comment: Opted for repr(array) solution (see comment above)

Comment: @user1609104 - It sounds like you might be using `eval` somewhere. You don't need to do this, and moreover you shouldn't. Could you post your code?

Comment: p = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
p = np.append(p, [[7],[8],[9]],1)
ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis mus
t match exactly

Comment: I think you can't skip the ```p = np.append(p, [[5,6]], 0)``` command otherwise the axis is too short for the next command

Answer (score 4):

You'll have problems creating lists without commas. It shouldn't be too hard to transform your data so that it uses commas as separating character.

Once you have commas in there, it's a relatively simple list creation operations:

```
array1 = [1,2,3]
array2 = [4,5,6]

array3 = [array1, array2]

array4 = [7,8,9]
array5 = [10,11,12]

array3 = [array3, [array4, array5]]
```

When testing we get:

```
print(array3)

[[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], [[7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]]
```

And if we test with indexing it works correctly reading the matrix as made up of 2 rows and 2 columns:

```
array3[0][1]
[4, 5, 6]

array3[1][1]
[10, 11, 12]
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

If the file is only numerical values separated by tabs, try using the csv library:
http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html
(you can set the delimiter to '\t')

If you have a textual file in which every line represents a row in a matrix and has integers separated by spaces\tabs, wrapped by a 'arrayname = [...]' syntax, you should do something like:

```
import re
f = open("your-filename", 'rb')
result_matrix = []
for line in f.readlines():
    match = re.match(r'\s*\w+\s+\=\s+\[(.*?)\]\s*', line)
    if match is None:
        pass # line syntax is wrong - ignore the line
    values_as_strings = match.group(1).split()
    result_matrix.append(map(int, values_as_strings))
```

Comment: Thanks, just added a comment above.

Answer (score -1):

```
a=np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
a.tolist()
```

`tolist` method mentioned above will return the nested Python list.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer to help the original poster and also others that come to read your answer.