# Array of coordinate sets in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib

I'm generating an image with Bezier curves and matplotlib, and I'm feeding my algorithm arrays that contain sets of coordinates in the following format:

```
back = [
(186, 615),     # near neck (P0)
(268, 756),     # (P1)
(460, 720),     # (P2)
(447, 630)      # near tail (P3)
]

tailmid = [
(562, 496),     # near back (P0)
(588, 423),     # (P1)
(441, 319),     # (P2)
(432,333)       # LEG VERTEX (P3)
]
```

The image needs a LOT of these coordinate sets to generate the necessary curves so I was thinking about putting each of these sets in an element of an array, which I'll iterate through and feed each element to functions of matplotlib. The problem is I'm fairly new to Python, and I'm not sure I can build an array of these sets. I've tried functions of Numpy [as mentioned in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12020872/array-of-arrays-python-numpy), but that doesn't seem to fit my data. Anyone have suggestions?

Comment: You list of tuples can easily be converted to a numpy array with: `np.array(back)`. The result can that be index identically to pure python i.e. `back[0][0]` or using numpy's syntax (recommended) `back[0,0]`.

Comment: Thanks @Ophion, that does work! However, given that my data doesn't have purely integers (the easiest data type to work with when using numpy), I ended up initializing an array of coordinate sets the vanilla way like so:



`fox = [[(307, 0), (-100, 50), (-100, 750), (307, 845)], 
    [(307, 845), (714, 750), (714, 50), (307, 0)]]`

The array starts out with two sets of coordinates. I then used Numpy's "append()" function to put additional coordinate sets in the array: `fox.append(['''some set of coords'''])`