# Declare array inside an array in Python equivalent to PHP

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

In php I can declare array inside an array like this:

```
$top_array['array1']['array2'] = array('Tom' => '21',
                                       'Tim' => '22');
```

how do you do that in python?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12020872/array-of-arrays-python-numpy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python

```
array1 = [ array2 ]
```

For example :

```
array2 = [1, 2, 3]
array1 = [ array2 ]
```

result will be

```
array1 = [[1,2,3]]
```

Here `array1` is an array of another array named `array2`

Similarly we can put multiple arrays in array1 like :

`array1 = [array2, array3, ...]`

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed 