# How do I add a column to a python (matix) multi-dimensional array?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, numpy, matplotlib

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the simplest way to extend a numpy array in 2 dimensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/877479/whats-the-simplest-way-to-extend-a-numpy-array-in-2-dimensions)

I've been frustrated as a Matlab user switching over to python because I don't know all the tricks and get stuck hacking together code until it works. Below is an example where I have a matrix that I want to add a dummy column to. Surely, there is a simpler way then the zip vstack zip method below. It works, but it is totally a noob attempt. Please enlighten me. Thank you in advance for taking the time for this tutorial.

```
# BEGIN CODE

from pylab import *

# Find that unlike most things in python i must build a dummy matrix to 
# add stuff in a for loop. 
H = ones((4,10-1))
print "shape(H):"
print shape(H)
print H
### enter for loop to populate dummy matrix with interesting data...
# stuff happens in the for loop, which is awesome and off topic.
### exit for loop
# more awesome stuff happens...
# Now I need a new column on H
H = zip(*vstack((zip(*H),ones(4)))) # THIS SEEMS LIKE THE DUMB WAY TO DO THIS...
print "shape(H):"
print shape(H)
print H

# in conclusion. I found a hack job solution to adding a column
# to a numpy matrix, but I'm not happy with it.
# Could someone educate me on the better way to do this?

# END CODE
```

Comment: I think [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/877564/1240268) might help you.

Answer (score 2):

Use [np.column_stack](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html#numpy-column-stack):

```
In [12]: import numpy as np

In [13]: H = np.ones((4,10-1))

In [14]: x = np.ones(4)

In [15]: np.column_stack((H,x))
Out[15]: 
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]])

In [16]: np.column_stack((H,x)).shape
Out[16]: (4, 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several functions that let you [concatenate](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) arrays in different dimensions:

- [`np.vstack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html) along `axis=0`
- [`np.hstack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html) along `axis=1`
- [`np.dstack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html) along `axis=2`

In your case, the `np.hstack` looks what you want. [`np.column_stack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html) stacks a set 1D arrays as a 2D array, but you have already a 2D array to start with.

Of course, nothing prevents you to do it the hard way:

```
>>> new = np.empty((a.shape[0], a.shape[1]+1), dtype=a.dtype)
>>> new.T[:a.shape[1]] = a.T
```

Here, we created an empty array with an extra column, then used some tricks to set the first columns to `a` (using the transpose operator `T`, so that `new.T` has an extra row compared to `a.T`...)