# python - Extend 2-d array and interpolate the missing values

Tags: python, interpolation

I have an array with size 48x80, now I want to extend the array in to a new one with size 117x192.
I have read about [scipy.interpolate](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html), but it doesn't mention about extending.

How can I extend the array and put the values into the new array?

FOR EXAMPLE:
Given array A [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

```
[1 2 3]
[4 5 6]
[7 8 9]
```

Now I want to extend array A to array B size 5x7

```
1 x 2 x 3
x x x x x
x x x x x
4 x 5 x 6
x x x x x
x x x x x
7 x 8 x 9
```

In which, replace these 'x' with interpolated values.

EXAMPLE 2:
In more general array

```
[4 2 6 4]
[4 34 6 2]
[2 11 3 4]
[2 4 22 4]
[2 1 35 255]
[1 3 4 54]
[22 1 4 5]
```

What should I do if I want a new array in size 20x30

UPDATE:
I figured out that there's a difference that makes @nicoguaro answer doesn't work in my case:

His solution:

```
pts = np.array([[i,j] for i in np.linspace(0,1,n) for j in np.linspace(0,1,m)] )
grid_x, grid_y = np.mgrid[0:1:m*2j, 0:1:n*2j]
```

My solution:

```
pts = np.array([[i,j] for i in np.linspace(0,2*m-1,m) for j in np.linspace(0,2*n-1,n)] )
grid_x, grid_y = np.mgrid[0:m*2, 0:n*2]
```

It leads to difference result. In fact, his solution works in most cases but TIFF file, I guess

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the simplest way to extend a numpy array in 2 dimensions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/877479/whats-the-simplest-way-to-extend-a-numpy-array-in-2-dimensions)

Comment: this one talking about append one or more rows to 2-D array

Comment: I think you need to be a lot more specific about what you're asking.

Comment: Have a look at `scipy.ndimage.zoom`.  For your example, you'd want `result = ndimage.zoom(data, (7.0/3, 5.0/3))`.  (Note that `scipy.ndimage` functions preserve type, so you'll need to explicitly cast your input to floats if you want floating point output.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although interpolate does not have a function for this particular task, you can easily use the built-in option to do it. Using the same example that you propose

```
[1 2 3]
[4 5 6]
[7 8 9]
```

to

```
1 x 2 x 3
x x x x x
x x x x x
4 x 5 x 6
x x x x x
x x x x x
7 x 8 x 9
```

We can use this code

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.interpolate as inter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

A = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
vals = np.reshape(A, (9))
pts = np.array([[i,j] for i in [0.0, 0.5, 1.0] for j in [0.0, 0.5, 1.0]] )
grid_x, grid_y = np.mgrid[0:1:7j, 0:1:5j]
grid_z = inter.griddata(pts, vals, (grid_x, grid_y), method='linear')
```

That gives as result

```
array([[ 1. ,  1.5,  2. ,  2.5,  3. ],
       [ 2. ,  2.5,  3. ,  3.5,  4. ],
       [ 3. ,  3.5,  4. ,  4.5,  5. ],
       [ 4. ,  4.5,  5. ,  5.5,  6. ],
       [ 5. ,  5.5,  6. ,  6.5,  7. ],
       [ 6. ,  6.5,  7. ,  7.5,  8. ],
       [ 7. ,  7.5,  8. ,  8.5,  9. ]])
```

or, as images

[image: Original image]

[image: Interpolated image]

In this case I used `griddata` that interpolates a set function (`vals`) defined over a set of points (`pts`) to a given rectilinear grid (given by `grid_x` and `grid_y`). If, for example, you want to use `nx` points for $x$ and `ny` for $y$, you can replace one line

```
grid_x, grid_y = np.mgrid[0:1:nx*1j, 0:1:ny*1j]
```

for `nx=20` and `ny=15` we got this image

[image]

You can see more examples at the [documentation of the function](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html).

**Update:** Including Example 2, where the matrix is

```
A = np.array([[4, 2, 6, 4],
            [4, 34, 6, 2],
            [2, 11, 3, 4],
            [2, 4, 22, 4],
            [2, 1, 35, 255],
            [1, 3, 4, 54],
            [22, 1, 4, 5]])
```

and for a new array of size 20x30. The code is below

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.interpolate as inter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

A = np.array([[4, 2, 6, 4],
            [4, 34, 6, 2],
            [2, 11, 3, 4],
            [2, 4, 22, 4],
            [2, 1, 35, 255],
            [1, 3, 4, 54],
            [22, 1, 4, 5]])
vals = np.reshape(A, (28))
pts = np.array([[i,j] for i in np.linspace(0,1,4) for j in np.linspace(0,1,7)] )
grid_x, grid_y = np.mgrid[0:1:20j, 0:1:30j]
grid_z = inter.griddata(pts, vals, (grid_x, grid_y), method='linear')

plt.matshow(A)
plt.matshow(grid_z)
plt.show()
```

The resulting images are:
[image: Example 2]
[image: Interpolated matrix in example 2]

Comment: Thanks for replying! There are things that I do not understand here: the purpose of pts, grid_x, grid_y. What it would be changed if I want a new array in size m(rows)x n (columns)

Comment: `pts` are the points where you know the values, in the case of an image these are given by a rectilinear grid. `grid_x` and `grid_y` are the points where do you want to interpolate the values, i.e., the _new_ places. You can see the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html) for an explanation.

Comment: I just expanded the answer.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get it. I just update the question with new example in more general

Comment: It runs properly, but the result looks weird. I think it due to my actual data is different. Here is my original data in row[21] [ 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 5.28000021 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.06 0.15000001 0.02999997 0.50999999 0. 0. 2.70000005 7.40999985 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. ]