# How to append multiple matrices in python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, append

I have read the following related discussions
[What's the simplest way to extend a numpy array in 2 dimensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/877479/whats-the-simplest-way-to-extend-a-numpy-array-in-2-dimensions)

However, if I want to expend multiple matrices, for example

```
A = np.matrix([[1,2],[3,4]])
B = np.matrix([[3,4],[5,6]])
C = np.matrix([[7,8],[5,6]])
F = np.append(A,[[B]],0)
```

However, python says

> ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 2 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 4 dimension(s)

I want to put B "under" the matrix A, and put C "under" the matrix B.
So, F should be a 6X2 matrix.

How to do this?  Thanks!

Comment: Since all your arrays have the same shape, you can simply `np.concatenate([A,B,C], axis=0)`.  I objected to the use of `np.append` in your linked answer, and will do so again.

Comment: What's the shape of `np.array([[B]])`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using numpy.concatenate (https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html):

```
A = np.matrix([[1,2],[3,4]])
B = np.matrix([[3,4],[5,6]])
C = np.matrix([[7,8],[5,6]])
# F = np.append(A,[[B]],0)
F = np.concatenate((A, B, C), axis=1)
```

Change the axis parameter to 0 to combine the matrices 'vertically':

```
print(np.concatenate((A, B, C), axis=1))
```

> [[1 2 3 4 7 8]
> [3 4 5 6 5 6]]

```
print(np.concatenate((A, B, C), axis=0))
```

> [[1 2]
> [3 4]
> [3 4]
> [5 6]
> [7 8]
> [5 6]]

Answer (score 2):

I believe np.concatenate should do the trick

```
    A = np.matrix([[1,2],[3,4]])
    B = np.matrix([[3,4],[5,6]])
    C = np.matrix([[7,8],[5,6]])
    ABC = np.concatenate([A,B,C],axis = 0) # axis 0 stacks it one above the other
    
    print("Shape : ",ABC.shape)
    print(ABC)
```

Output :

```
    Shape : (6, 2)
    matrix(
    [[1, 2],
    [3, 4],
    [3, 4],
    [5, 6],
    [7, 8],
    [5, 6]])
```

Comment: But why do two `concatenate`?  It's more efficient the do one with `[A,B,C]`.